# How to add "selectize" in a asp.net core project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, selectlist

I'm a very beginner in code.
I created my first asp.net core app and I try to create a select list with icons.
I'd like to use this solution : https://jsfiddle.net/maxmx/e0380p0o

This is my cshtml file :

```
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.11.0/css/selectize.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.11.0/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.11.0/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.email-select').selectize({
        valueField: 'name',
        labelField: 'name',
        placeholder: 'Select somebody'
        , options: [{
            description: 'Nice Guy',
            name: 'Brian Reavis',
            imageUrl: '~/img/download.jpg'
        }, {
            description: 'Other nice guy',
            name: 'Nikola Tesla',
            imageUrl: '~/img/download.jpg'
        }],
        render: {
            option: function (item, escape) {
                return '<div class="option">' +
                    '<div class="image">' +
                    '<img class="avatar" src="' + item.imageUrl + '" />' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="text">' +
                    '<span class="name">' + escape(item.name) + '</span>' +
                    '<p class="description">' + escape(item.description) + '</p>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<select class="email-select"></select>
</body>
```

[This is what is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWqzk.png)

Comment: I can not spot any error - open your browser debug tools and check for javascript errors - or for files that are not loaded. - the core did not have nothing to do with this code - this is  javascript code that is not run correctly

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the browser debug and there is absolutely nothing logged. All the scripts are loaded, I can find them in the debugger. Very weird. I don't know why my js code is not run...

Comment: put this on top of your html page `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it did not change anything...